# Auto tab to the next fields depending upon the field type

Tags: html

I find it intriguing and couldn't find any special reason as to why the cursor should not advance to the next form field when the field type is "drop-down selection" or "radio button". As in both cases logically there cannot be any additional input.

Is there any attribute which can be applied so that the cursor moves on to the next field.

Consider how many forms are filled daily worldwide and how much time being wasted if there is no special reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STOP!  What you are trying to do will break keyboard users.  In fact, [any change you make will break *somebody's* workflow](http://xkcd.com/1172/).

Auto-tab should not be used for any field, *ever*.

Who knows your field is going to auto tab?  Nobody.  Why?  Because that's not what fields do on the web.  So, I press tab out of habit to get to the next field, what did I do?  Oh no, I've tabbed *past* the next field, thanks to an unexpected auto-tab.  Now I'll just have to tab back.

I'm editing a field, there are enough characters in the field already, I want to overwrite some characters in the field, oh no!  I'm being auto-tabbed out of it before I can finish!

I'm a keyboard user, I use the up and down arrows to change the value in a select or radio.  These are triggering onchange events every time I press them, even though I haven't finished changing the value to the value I want.

When I want to tab to the next field, I'll jolly well press it myself thanks.

There is a very special reason not to autotab, and this doesn't really waste any time (unless you're developing something for somebody to use constantly for several hours at a time).  The special reason is you're following the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: I am not talking about autotab on normal text fields, where you use keyboard. if you have a "drop-down field" or a radio button field where you click one option, I am asking a logic, why the cursor should sit there once I have made the selection, if there is a wrong logic, wrong habit that can always be changed.

Comment: @Pawan you don't understand. 1: There should not be autotab on *any* field.  2: You can still use keyboard for all fields.  What cursor?  Do you mean focus?  There is not wrong logic, or habit.  Auto tab is only productive in highly repetitive workflows (I'm talking constant use of the *same* user interface, like a cashier for example).  How do you know when a keyboard user has finished selecting from a drop-down select?

Answer (score 0):

Start with attribute tabindex="-1"

JQuery style:
    $('.something').each(function(){
        this.tabIndex = -1;
    });

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was asking for logic and it looks like I have found a reasonable answer to myself.

The cursor stays there and doesn't auto-tab to the next field as next field type may be a radio field or again a drop-down selection field, where auto-tab cannot take any action for example selecting an option from multiple radio options.

But I still feel that there should be an option of auto-tab depending on where it can be used or where it can be omitted.

Comment: You can always move focus to the next form field using the tab key, even to radio buttons and select boxes.  This is not the reason why there is no auto tab option.  The reason is that you don't know when the user has finished making a selection.  Like you don't know when the user has finished typing into a fixed-length text field, what if the last character was a typo?

Comment: I never questioned the auto-tab from a text field to the next field. I was questioning the behevior about radio button field or a drop-down field, where the program can very well know the click action on the radio option or drop-down option when you finished clicking as there is just one option.

Comment: Yes, but 'click' does not imply mouse.  Auto-tab is a keyboard-related action, when you control radio buttons or drop-downs with a keyboard, there is no 'click'.  You could press space, but there would be no need, since you'll already have selected that option with the arrow keys prior to pressing space, the user just moves to the next field to indicate 'click', hence no-auto-tab.  Your question presumed there was an auto-tab for text fields (by giving the question a html5 tag), but there isn't auto-tab for text fields either, so why even the question?!

Answer (score 0):

Auto tab is an important and needed feature. Why, for example, should I have to press the tab key after entering in my area code before I can type in the next 3 numbers? From a user experience perspective, that's really annoying. I would think there would be an attribute built into HTML5 or CSS3 to accomplish this. I found this thread as I'm looking for it. If anyone has an update, please share.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question